# How to set the current pathname as current state on onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have created 3 categories - sports, entertainment, and science. I want to set the current pathname as the state on onClick but in actual previous pathname is setting as the current state onClick.

For example-

if I am on the sports page the pathname is /sports and on click the state is setting to /sports but when iam clicking the other category for example technology, the pathname is setting to /technology and when onClick the state is now setting to previous pathname ie /sports and not current pathname which is /technology and i want current pathway that is /technology to be set as state on onClick and not previous pathway.

```
// the state

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Country: "in",
      Link: "/" ,
      dropText : "Select Country"
    };
  } 

//on click function 

ConInd = () => {
    this.setState({ Country: "in" });
    this.setState({ Link: window.location.pathname});
    this.setState({ dropText : "India"});
  };


// on Click element 

 <li><Link className="dropdown-item" onClick={this.props.ConInd} to={this.props.Currlink}>India</Link></li>

// the prop passed 

 Currlink={this.state.Link}
```

Comment: Why can't you just read the URL path from the component? What's the point of saving it into any local state? I know based on one of your previous questions you stated you are trying to only use class-based components, but really, that's like a fish swimming upstream in today's React ecosystem. Declare a route where the "category" is a route path param and use the `useParams` hook to read it. There's really not any compelling reason to store it in state that I can see.

Comment: @DrewReese actually i have to shift my whole component to functional based and i guess i would surely mess something while doing it...so i wanted to implement it in class component...whats the alternative of useParams in class component?

Comment: There isn't one, per se, but depending on what `react-router` version you are using you have route prop if the class component is rendered directly by a `Route` component or if it isn't the `withRouter` Higher Order Component to inject them as props if using RRDv5, but if you are using RRDv6 you have neither. If you are using class components and don't convert to function components then you'll need to roll your own "withRouter" HOC to use the hooks and inject the params as a prop. Do you know what version of `react-router` you are using?